# Saving images from Cordova app to Parse.com with REST API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform

I am building an ionic application using the Parse.com MBaaS for the data storage. The issue that I have is with regards to saving images to Parse and then displaying the image using the url that is created dynamically. So far I have the image capture working correctly, and then I use ajax to post the file to the backend, which I can see from the control panel has worked correctly. However, when I then try and display the image using the url that is stored in the 'file' row of the class, a broken image link is displayed.

The image displays correctly using the FILE_URI provided by cordova before posting it to Parse.

Are there further steps that need to be taken to display the image saved in Parse.com?

Here isthey code which I've broken up with dome details:

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
    var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/image.jpg';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", ParseConfiguration.applicationId);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", '##############');
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'image/jpeg');
    },
    url: serverUrl,
    data: imagePath,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var diaryIm = new Parse.Object("images");
        diaryIm.set({imagetitle: data.name});
        diaryIm.set({imageurl: data.url});
```

The data.url returned at this point would be for example http://files.parsetfss.com/fc83a434-e6a908d13ce8/tfss-fd4eb5fbf37d-image.jpg

```
        $scope.theUser[$scope.thisDay]['photo'] = data.url;
        diaryIm.set({imagefile: {"name": data.name,"url": data.url,"__type": "File"}});
        diaryIm.save(null, {
            success: function(data){
```

At this point the file is now saved in in my 'images' class with the new url as described above.

```
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.error);
    }
    });
}
```

I greatly appreciate any advice that can be given on this, thanks.

Comment: is any specific error you are getting ?

Comment: No errors, the success callback is fired each time and returns the parse.com file url for my image. It is just that the url displays only a broken image instead of the photography that was uploaded.

Comment: did you get data.url properly ? have you debugged it ?

Comment: Yeah, the data object returns both the file name (as created by Parse eg. tfss-fd4eb5fbf37d-image.jpg) and the url eg.  http://files.parsetfss.com/e6a908d13ce8/tfss-fd4eb5fbf37d-image.jpg